# Get CDATA using xml.etree.ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

I have the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<testsuite errors="1" failures="0" name="test" tests="1" time="3.393">
        <testcase classname="test" name="case time="3.393">
                <error message="'test' object has no attribute 'test'" type="AttributeError">
<![CDATA["HERES THE DETAILED ERROR"]]>             </error>
        </testcase>
        <system-out>
<![CDATA["ANOTHER TEXT"]]>
 </system-out>
        <system-err>
<![CDATA[]]>    </system-err>
</testsuite>
```

and I have the following parsing code:

```
tree = ET.parse("test-reports/{0}".format(resultfile))
test = tree.getroot()
for child in test:
    if child.tag == "testcase":
        if child.find("error") is not None:
            state = 2
            # How do I get <error>s CDATA here?
        else:
            state = 1
```

How would I achieve getting the CDATA text inside the  tag (the first CDATA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do -

```
ertag = child.find("error")
cdatatext = ertag.text
print(cdatatext)
```

This would print -

```
"HERES THE DETAILED ERROR"
```